# modify columns for a list of data frames

Tags: r, list

I have multiple tables loaded using lapply. The last colname is not the same for all tables which makes it impossible to `rbind` the tables. I would like to make a new column that contains the colname in column 10 as ID, then rename the colname of column 10 to X.

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "edit")
tables <- lapply(file_list, read.csv, header = T, sep="\t")

colnames(tables[[984]])

 [1] "X.CHROM"                                      "POS"                                          "ID"                                          
 [4] "REF"                                          "ALT"                                          "QUAL"                                        
 [7] "FILTER"                                       "INFO"                                         "FORMAT"                                      
[10] "ID02020886"
```

My try:

```
tables <- map2(tables, file_list, ~cbind(.x, ID = .y)) #Does not work....
```

Desired out:

```
colnames(tables[[984]])

 [1] "X.CHROM"                                      "POS"                                          "ID"                                          
 [4] "REF"                                          "ALT"                                          "QUAL"                                        
 [7] "FILTER"                                       "INFO"                                         "FORMAT"                                      
[10] "X"                                            "ID"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a loop. I named the new column ID_new as another ID column is already there.

```r
# sample data
tables <- lapply(c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3"), function(id) {
  cnames <- c("X.CHROM", "POS", "ID", "REF", "ALT", "QUAL", "FILTER", "INFO", 
              "FORMAT", id)
  as.data.frame(sapply(cnames, function(x) rnorm(5)))
})

# modify tables one by one
for (i in seq_along(tables)) {
  
  tables[[i]] <- cbind(tables[[i]], 
                       ID_new=colnames(tables[[i]])[10])
  colnames(tables[[i]])[10] <- 'X'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I get an error, probably due to some tables don't have any rows (empty): Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

Comment: Maybe I can filter out the tables that have no rows?

Comment: Yes, maybe you can start with something like `tables <- tables[sapply(tables, nrow) > 0]`.

Comment: Worked by removing files with no rows

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, with built-in data set `mtcars` to test the code.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(purrr)
})

file_list<- letters[1:2]
tables <- list(head(mtcars)[-1], head(mtcars)[-ncol(mtcars)])

tables %>%
  map2(file_list, ~cbind(.x, ID = .y)) %>%
  map( ~rename(.x, 'X' = names(.x)[10]))
#> [[1]]
#>                   cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear X ID
#> Mazda RX4           6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4 4  a
#> Mazda RX4 Wag       6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4 4  a
#> Datsun 710          4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4 1  a
#> Hornet 4 Drive      6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3 1  a
#> Hornet Sportabout   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3 2  a
#> Valiant             6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3 1  a
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am X ID
#> Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1 4  b
#> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1 4  b
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1 4  b
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0 3  b
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0 3  b
#> Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0 3  b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>